# Regex extract, remove duplicates, and join with a pipe in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, textjoin

I have rows of data like the following:

```
Cat A>Subcat A|Cat A>Subcat B
Cat A>Subcat C|Cat B>Subcat A|Cat B>Subcat C|Cat C
```

You'll notice that it's basically a list of parent categories and subcategories separated by a pipe `|`

I am needing to extract data from each row in two following ways:

1. Get all parent categories and separate them by a pipe `|` (removing duplicates).
2. Get all subcategory names and separate them by a pipe `|` (removing duplicates).

From those first two provided rows, the result should look like:

| String | Parents (Result 1) | Children (Result 2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat A>Subcat A|Cat A>Subcat B | Cat A | Subcat A|Subcat B |
| Cat A>Subcat C|Cat B>Subcat A|Cat B>Subcat C|Cat C | Cat A|Cat B|Cat C | Subcat C|Subcat A |

I've been able to achieve partial results using `REGEXEXTRACT` and `JOIN` but it either matches only once, or returns multiple. Example:

```
# Returns the first instance of "Cat A" only
=REGEXEXTRACT(H2,"(.*?)>.*?\|")
```

I'm looking to get help creating two regex patterns that can get the desired "Result 1" and "Result 2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(
 IFNA(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A2)&"×"&
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A2&">", "|", 1), "(.*)>"), "(>.*)", )))&"|", "×")), 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0),,9^9)), "| ", "|")), "\|$", ))
```

[image]

and:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(
 IFNA(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A2)&"×"&
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A2, "|", 1), ">(.*)"), "(>.*)", )))&"|", "×")), 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0),,9^9))), "| ", "|")), "\|$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Funny, player0: I was just coming on to post exactly the same solution. The only differences were what I chose as temporary join/split characters. Great minds and such...

Comment: When posting this, I said to myself "I bet this is a walk in the park for player0." I was right. You nailed it again my friend. I need to stop looking for regex-specific solutions and just hack it up with queries :)  THANKS!